# How do I set a column to be unique, but only under a condition?

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table, which has an ID, a column "A" and other columns. If A is set to "this", there can't be another ID with it's column A set to "this". Else, there can be many entries of that ID with multiple values set for column "A".

Ex.:

```
ID | A | other columns
```

this is allowed:

```
1 | that | ...
1 | something | ...
1 | foo | ...
```

but this is not:

```
1 | this | ...
1 | that | ...
```

(the 3 dots mean it doesn't matter what data we have there)

I'm doing this on MySQL Workbench, so it would be much appreciated if your answer showed me how to do it there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a trigger that will fire before every INSERT or UPDATE statement (for each row) and check whether or not your constraint is valid and the row can or cannot be added. AFAIK in MySQL you actually need to have two triggers (one for each action), but there is nothing stopping you from wrapping up your validation within a procedure and call it from both triggers.

I'll give you the starters for further tweaking.

1.Create insert trigger

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_trg //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trg 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtable
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL yourprocedure(<arguments here>);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

2.Create update trigger analogously to the insert trigger

3.Create procedure with the validation code

---

SQL to validate your constraint will look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable yt
WHERE yt.id = NEW.id -- replace with arguments passed to procedure
  AND yt.A  = NEW.A  -- same as above
```

You most likely need to wrap it up with an `EXISTS` statement and if statement

---

Some source of knowledge:

- [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- [Create Procedure Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)